# Add migrate to Home Brewing in flag menu

Tags: feature-request, migration, flagging

In flag menu option **needs improvement** > **a community specific reason** > **This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network** I think [Home Brewing](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/) should be added. As of now only [alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/) is there.

Answer (score 3):

There are so-called [migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203318/295232) and not all sites have them; one of the footnotes in the [FAQ about migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/295232) says this:

> <sup>2</sup> Not every site has selectable migration paths; in particular, beta sites, recently-graduated sites, and Meta Stack Exchange don't have any selectable sites (other than the site's per-site meta, if applicable, and vice versa). On such sites, only moderators can migrate questions out of that site (as they can choose any site to migrate to).